# What happens between fetch() and catch()

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

```
const data = { username: 'example'};
function fetchRequest(counter: number) {
    fetch('https://example.com/profile', {
        method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
    .then((response: Response) => {
        console.log('responded:' + counter);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
}
//lost connection to https://example.com/profile
fetchRequest(1);
// 500 ms passed
// restored connection to https://example.com/profile
fetchRequest(2);
```

In the snippet above is it possible that we get:

```
responded: 2
responded: 1
```

?
Or is the first post request going to be sent first because under the hood the "fetch" function queues requests so that when another fetch is called to the same address it first sends all the queued requests? Or does the first request start its internal timeout for re sending so that it tries sending the first request say every 300 ms, so it fails to send the first time but succeeds on the second time )after the second request was sent successfully)?

The problem is that I am making post requests over an eventually dead connection. The thing that has led to this question is that when there is no connection the fetch has a 2 minute cool down before it calls catch(). Even if the connection is restored, the initial request will still wait all those 2 minutes before it throws.

It so happened that the order of requests I send matters so I can't just resend on catch, because during this cool down some other requests could have been successfully sent. Although this wouldn't be a big problem, if no attempts are made by the system to send the initial request during this cool down. And that is the thing I am trying to make sure of, but can't find any information about.

So any advice on that would be very much appreciated.

Edit: In other words...lets look at the situation:

A fetch() is called with some request when there is no connection (so fetch goes into 2 sec timeout). Within 1 second the connection restores and another fetch is called.

Is there a guarantee that the first request would be sent by the framework before the second one? Could it be that the second request is sent first, then in another minute the first one is sent?

Answer (score -1):

In your example, the order of responses is never guaranteed, since it also depends on the backend. If the backend completes 2nd request first, the 2nd response would be returned first. It's not just about how the frontend executes the order of fetch requests, so in your example, since you dont' call `fetchRequest(1)` and `fetchRequest(2)` asynchronously, there is no way to ensure 1st response comes before 2nd response.

> Or does the first request start its internal timeout for re sending so
> that it tries sending the first request say every 300 ms

I don't have much understanding about this layer, but as long as the TCP connection of the request stays alive, the request still can hang on until either it's reconnected or the TCP connection is destroyed.

To your specific questions:

> Is there a guarantee that the first request would be sent by the
> framework before the second one?

callback, promise or async-await is what you might need here. Chain your request asynchronously allows previous request to be finished before the next one executes. Here is a simple example of how to rewrite your example using Promise

```
function fetchRequest(counter) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fetch('https://example.com/profile', {
        method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log('responded:' + counter);
        resolve(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        reject(error);
    });
  })
}

fetchRequest(1)
  .then((resp) => fetchRequest(2))
  .catch(e => console.log(e))
```

async-await is neater for long request chains, btw.

> Even if the connection is restored, the initial request will still
> wait all those 2 minutes before it throws.

For this I have no answer, but you can try to reduce waiting time by [throttle](https://kriss.io/javascript-throttle-and-debounce-concept-and-comparision/) the request. You can use library lodash for built-in throttle method.

Comment: "*Here is a simple example of how to rewrite your example using Promise*" - OP is already using promises! Don't introduce the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!